# How to remove filled area on SE when plot "geom_smooth" in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I would like to plot a `geom_smooth()` in ggplot2 without filled `se`, but only the two edges of the **se**.

I have tried to use the code `geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, fill=NA)`, but it doesn't give what I expected.

```
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2)+
      geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=T)
```

[image: Something like the figure shows]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution:

```
gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(fill = "transparent")

ggg <- ggplot_build(gg)

dat <- ggg$data[[2]]

gg + geom_line(aes(x, ymin), data=dat, linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(x, ymax), data=dat, linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `fill = NA`. Otherwise the area is not fully transparent.

Answer (score 3):

May be something like this? Failed to skip the vertical lines at two end.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       mapping = aes(x = wt,
                     y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess",
              se = FALSE,
              colour = "black") +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth",
              method = "loess",
              se = TRUE,
              alpha = 0, # or, use fill = NA
              colour = "black",
              linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]